# Why Object.keys().map wrapped in a conditional in typescript is telling it can be null or undefined?

Tags: typescript, conditional-statements

I am trying to return a value from the map method after using the Object.keys(obj) wrapped in a conditional, but typescript is always showing the error: `is possibly 'null' or 'undefined'`.

This is the code I have written:

```ts
interface IPayload {
    section?: {
        title?: string | null
    } | null;
}

const payload: IPayload = {
    section: null
}

if (payload && payload.section) {
    Object.keys(payload).map((key) => {
        return payload.section[key as keyof typeof payload.section];
    });
}
```

Here is the [link to playground typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIAU4E8A2B7OAE2QG8AoZS5AZwgTGDxAH4AuUiqrhsHCNmmCigA5sgA+yEAFccOTpQC+EqbJwBuMorJkETamGQAHbPiLsMpgsQC8HLrXqMQ7GXK07gMZAAoTua2QAMiDjKyIAOkcGJgBKeyoAeQAjACs6MAiAawgsaj9wwliIgFs4Ix8fHKx4mwA+BK5KKAgwaSgQMIDI6OcAbWrkOGpkarxvMCwjCHGus0IojOcAXU0uRVjNbSA) of the code

if the conditional is `payload && payload.section`, then I think it should be enough to check if  **payload and section** have value and is not: undefined, null or false.

if I change the return to: `return payload.section && payload.section[key as keyof typeof payload.section];` it works because I am checking it inline, but I am checking the same twice.

so I don't understand why the first payload.section in the map method is not working.

Thanks you for your time.

Comment: See the linked questions/answers, as well as [ms/TS#9998](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998)

Comment: Thank you so much, this helped me to understand what is happening.
And sorry for the duplicate question but I didn't find the answer before.